# First argument for Url.Parser.custom in Elm

Tags: elm, url-parsing

The docs for [`Url.Parser.custom`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/url/latest/Url-Parser#custom) give an example:

```
int : Parser (Int -> a) a
int =
  custom "NUMBER" String.toInt
```

But don't indicate what `"NUMBER"` is used for.

---

I checked [the source](https://github.com/elm/url/blob/384b1dcf84065a500a71402ec367f3982b35093d/src/Url/Parser.elm#L144-L157) and it seems to be capture as `tipe`, but never used:

```
custom : String -> (String -> Maybe a) -> Parser (a -> b) b
custom tipe stringToSomething =
  Parser <| \{ visited, unvisited, params, frag, value } ->
    case unvisited of
      [] ->
        []

      next :: rest ->
        case stringToSomething next of
          Just nextValue ->
            [ State (next :: visited) rest params frag (value nextValue) ]

          Nothing ->
            []
```

So:

1. What is the purpose of `tipe`?
2. Does it matter what value it has?

Comment: My guess is that it's meant as a label to aid in debugging parser errors. Since it's not used it seems unlikely to matter. It might just be there to be able to provide better error messages in the future without breaking the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evan has addressed this in the following GitHub Issue: https://github.com/elm/url/issues/6

> tl;dr: It does nothing but is there for future use.